# Python code for finding the degree of rotation of an engineering drawing(in tif/png format)

Tags: python, image, png, tiff, image-rotation

I have a set of engineering drawings and certain diagrams  are rotated by either 90,180 or 270 degree. To get the correct image I need to find the angle by which it is rotated and rotate it by that angle. I need to automate this process using python.     So far I have come across a few methodologies like finding the exif data(it doesn't work in this case because these images initially were pdfs that were converted to tif/png files). I also have a few tilted diagrams within the normal engineering(i.e. doesn't need rotation)), thereby baring me from using the slope of a line to find the angle of rotation. From what I understand the rotation of the texts within the image can be used to find the angle to be rotated. But I am at a dead end on how to do that. Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Here is some interesting reading material (using python and PIL): https://gist.github.com/endolith/334196bac1cac45a4893

Comment: @inversivemedia thank you! It worked beautifully!